# How to pre-process rdd elements on driver machine and transform ready elements on executors concurrently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Spark application with logic flow as below:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val begin = 1
val end = 100
val arr = begin.until(end).toArray
val obj_arr = for(e <- arr) yield {val obj = new MyClass; obj.preprocess(e); obj}
rdd = sc.parallelize(obj_arr, 4)
rdd.map{x=>{x.transform()}}.collect()
```

`MyClass` is a class I defined to handle data, it has methods `preprocess()` and `transform()`. `preprocess()` prepares the data for `transform()`. The data into RDD is an array of `MyClass` instances as you can see. So far, it can work as my expectation to execute `transform()` on the executors in parallel.

However, I want to improve it for reducing runtime. In the implementation above, the `obj_arr` is created all at once with `obj.preprocess(e)` executed on the driver machine. Because both `preprocess()` and *transform()* are very slow, it takes a lot of time to finish creating obj_arr on the driver machine while during that period the executors are free. I hope that anytime an element in obj_arr is ready (i.e. its `preprocess()` is done), its associated task can be distributed to be executed on the executor immediately but not wait until the whole `obj_arr` is ready. **Since `preprocess()` needs a very huge data file stored on driver machine, I don't want to have it executed on executor to avoid transferring huge data over network. The huge data file cannot be sliced by Spark using default way, I have to load it by special model and retrieve data unit dynamically.** If the element creation for `obj_arr` can be made lazy, it may work, but I don't know how to do this way.

`preprocess()` needs data from a file whose size is more than 100G. This file is not a normal txt format or others that can be sliced by Spark. I have to load this file by a special model and retrieve data unit from it dynamically. The model with data loaded is more than 100G as well. If I included the whole model into every map task, a task will be more than 100G as well, I think it is crazy. Alternatively, I can broadcast this model. However, I thing that broadcasting a >100G variable to many executors may be still very slow.

Therefore, I can not create a rdd out of raw data and let Spark slice raw data for distribution.

Can you suggest how to implement the improvement?

Comment: Can I use streaming + Kafka? Preprocess data within Kafka on driver node and streaming pulls the data from the Kafka topic to transform them one by one. The way seems complicated and I am not sure whether it is effective as I am not familiar with Spark streaming at all.

Comment: I learnt that streaming +kafka is not effective for my case.Because the batches in streaming are evaluated sequentially. The last batch running will block new batch.